# How can I get my Linux kernel module to work across all processors?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, cpu, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module for an x86_64 Linux v3.19 machine that changes some control registers. I would like my changes to be uniform across the 4 processors I have, which as of now entails loading and unloading my module over-and-over until the control registers for all processors have been changed. Is there a way to loop through all processors in my kernel module and adjust the control registers (for example, `cr4`)?

In user space this might look something like masking the runnable CPUs, running the code, re-masking the runnable CPUs, running the code etc. with `sched_setaffinity(2)`.

Comment: IIRC, the Linux kernel has a `run_on` function you could use in a loop.  RCU needs that functionality so it's supported for kernel code.

Comment: There are a few kernel mechanisms for running code on specific cores. And, for intercore sync. But, the core kernel generally wants/needs to be aware of what goes into the control registers. So, _which_ control registers do you want to change and _why_? What, more generally, are you trying to achieve? In many cases, the kernel already has functions that manipulate control registers [in a controlled way, and sometimes, arch independent]. You may be able to get what you want by calling _them_ vs trying to access the control registers directly.

Comment: Hi @CraigEstey thanks for your reply. I am mainly trying to turn off and on extended features of the CPU to test their effects on different attacks one might conduct on the system. I have looked for specific functions to turn these features on and off but many of them use special instructions (for example, `xsetbv`) so I just wrote a bunch of code that does it. If possible, it would be great to be able to just set the affinity of the processors so I don't have to change any of my existing code.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am mainly interested in changing `cr4` and `xcr0`.

Comment: @CraigEstey I don't mind if the solution is hack-y as I am not trying to build an industry-quality kernel module -- I just want something to toy around with.

Comment: For a really simple test, you could just  boot with `nosmp` or perhaps `maxcpus=1`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah! Thank you :) this was a quick way to test what I needed. `maxcpus=1` worked well.